# How to detect when user presses "menu" key on their Android device?

Tags: android, android-activity, listener

I know I can override `onBackPressed()` on higher API levels to detect if the back key is pressed. Is there a similar way to do it for the menu button? I'm not a big fan of checking keycode in KeyEvents. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are just looking to create a key listener for the menu button you should be overriding [onKeyDown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) and checking the keycode. Now since you pointed out that you are not a big fan of that you could also override [onPrepareOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) which is called everytime the menu button is clicked and a menu is shown to the user. I am not sure if this is called if you have not supplied a menu inside the [onCreateOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) method.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I ended up inflating menu object in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and overrode `onOptionsItemSelected()`.

Comment: @bobbake4 how to listen when the menu is pressed second time  public void onOptionMenuClosed() is not working.

Comment: With no options menu defined on android 4.4.2, onPrepareOptionsMenu is only called right when activity starts and never again.

Comment: @velis You can use the call invalidateOptionsMenu() or supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() to cause a menu rebuild to happen.

Comment: It should not work.. I gave down  vote to this answer because its not even work or not a proper answer. I will share you my answer

Answer (score 16):

Are you in search of this????:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            //do your work
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew this method, but I'm not a big fan of checking keycode. I wanted something similar to `onBackPressed()`, not `if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)`.

Comment: If you take a look at the first few lines of the Activity source code, you will see that onBackPressed is called following the Back button keyCode:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onKeyDown%28int%2Candroid.view.KeyEvent%29

Comment: Does this still work with API 22? I have an app where the event does not fire on Home or Menu keys.

Comment: I have tried the same code but can't succeed in Oppo F3.