# How to add popup menu over videoview android?

Tags: android

I have a list of array items, And what i need is while clicking a specific key i want to show a popup listing the array items.

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
  {  

        switch(keyCode) {



            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
               keymenu();
              return true;

           }
        return false;


   } 


private void keymenu()
{
    PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(this, myvid);
    menu.getMenu().add("titleRes");
    menu.getMenu().add("titleRes1");
    menu.getMenu().add("titleRes2");
    menu.getMenu().add("titleRes3");
    menu.show();

}
```

I tried this and the pop is not showing while clicking the menu button.

Comment: what is your myvid parameter in PopupMenu()?

Comment: myvid is the name of VideoView. I need to show the popup menu over VideoView

Answer (score 0):

I think as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8264642) post you should override [onCreateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) and [onPrepareOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) as the doc says

> **public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu)** Added in API level 1
>
> Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. ***This is
>   called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown***. You can
>   use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise
>   dynamically modify the contents.
>
> The default implementation updates the system menu items based on the
>   activity's state. Deriving classes should always call through to the
>   base class implementation.

And call your `keymenu()` from there.